# I want to use eclipse without internet connection for create maven project

Tags: spring, maven, spring-boot

I created maven project in local where i have internet access.it is working fine but when i import same to server (i.e without internet access) it is showing error jars not found.please let me know what steps i have follow to run maven install and other commands to build the project without internet access in eclipse

Answer (score 2):

Where you have set up a project with an internet connection you can copy the contents of your .m2 folder (your local Maven repository) to your computer you are trying to develop without an internet connection.

This will provide you with all the .jars you used previously when you had an internet connection but if you need to add new dependencies this won't work without the internet.